# Google Material - Scroll div with set height

Tags: css, angular-material

I have a div of a set height. I am setting that div up with a column in google material and then adding rows of content.

My problem is this :

If I do not set the container div to have a fixed height, then the div is not scrollable - the overflow content is simply not shown.

If I set the container to a fixed height, then the rows are pushed together to fit into that space and the formatting is lost.

This seems like something that should be extremely simple to do. I see answers that say you should embed md-content elements which I have in the code below. This is frowned upon by the material docs and understandably so. Any help is appreciated.

```
<md-content>

    <md-content>

        <div layout="column" flex="100">

            <div layout="row" flex="100" layout-margin >

                row content

            </div>

            <div layout="row" flex="100" layout-margin >

                row content

            </div>

            <div layout="row" flex="100" layout-margin >

                row content

            </div>

        </div>

    </md-content>

</md-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set `flex="none"` for the inner `div`s - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/WxaXGQ)

From the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children)

[image]

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content>
      Scrolling:
      <md-content>
          <div layout="column" style="height:50px; background:yellow; overflow:auto">
              <div layout="row" flex="none" layout-margin style="color:red">
                  row content
              </div>
              <div layout="row" flex="none" layout-margin  style="color:blue">
                  row content
              </div>
              <div layout="row" flex="none" layout-margin  style="color:green">
                  row content
              </div>
          </div>
      </md-content>
      <br>
      Basic:
      <md-content>
          <div layout="column">
              <div layout="row" flex="100" layout-margin style="color:red">
                  row content
              </div>
              <div layout="row" flex="100" layout-margin  style="color:blue">
                  row content
              </div>
              <div layout="row" flex="100" layout-margin  style="color:green">
                  row content
              </div>
          </div>
      </md-content>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Any comments on the validity of using embedded md-content tags? Any other ideals as to what should be done?

Comment: @JoshuaFoxworth According to the docs - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdContent - "In general, `<md-content>` components are not designed to be nested inside one another. If possible, it is better to make them siblings. This often results in a better user experience as having nested scrollbars may confuse the user." I usually have one `md-content` in which I put all my elements and use divs to group elements. Hope that helps.